# Is the LISA language object oriented?

Tags: oop, arm, instruction-set

I came across some code in the LISA language while working on an ARM based project. The code look much similar like a mix of VHDL and C++. I tried to google out to get an introduction to the language. I couldn't find much help.If some one has good experience in LISA please guide in the approach to be taken in understanding the language design or basically what will be a good starting point to master it .
I got a link to the university where this has been found 
https://www.ice.rwth-aachen.de/research/tools-projects/lisa/lisa/

But on understanding this as a language(basically how to code in it) the information provided there is insufficient I feel . We don't even have a tag for this in SO!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question -

"LISA is a descriptive programming language and not object oriented"

You can go through this [Paper - LISA
Machine Description Language and
Generic Machine Model for
HWSW CoDesign](https://www.ice.rwth-aachen.de/fileadmin/publications/Zivojnovic96vlsi.pdf)
 for more details. The language has not been yet standardized by IEEE and ISO yet and is in its enhancement phase.

Comment: My expectation was some guide or Tutorial which make the language concepts  clear like the majority of the languages. But so far this is the best reply I got so I am accepting it.